# Header 'Transfer-Encoding' in Google Cloud Run

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, nestjs, google-cloud-run, transfer-encoding

Has anyone tested or worked with the response header : 'Transfer-Encoding' to obtain it as a response header in a service deployed in Cloud Run ?

I can't find it in my API response headers, if I create any other custom header I can get it.

Backend : NestJS

Comment: I can see you posted question in [cloud community support](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Header-Transfer-Encoding-in-Google-Cloud-Run/m-p/490739) and an answer has given there. You may follow up there.

Comment: It's not the response for my question, I asked about a non-existing header and they responded me about "server-streaming RPCs". Even if I was going to use the header for streaming, it's not a response to my question : why can't I find the header ?